# How to read HTTPS traffic without any configuration?

Tags: networking, proxy, network-shares, https, hotspot

I was able to analyze my iPhone's HTTP/HTTPS traffic through a shared network of Windows 10 PC with the help of burp. But this needed some proxy configuration and certificate installation on iPhone. What I want to achieve here is, I want to connect my iPhone to a hosted network of my PC and I would like to see the HTTPS traffic without any setup on the client-side

If I've understood correctly there is a [Burp support article](https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1841150-creating-an-ad-hoc-wireless-network-in-os-x) claiming to achieve this in OS X. Can I possibly achieve this in burp or any other software using any method or OS?

Comment: "_without any setup on the client-side_" ... you want to break TLS? (as per your question)

Comment: or do you want to setup an Ad-Hoc network between two devices? (as per the linked article)

Comment: @Attie the linked article doesn't seem to specify any client-side configuration for the Ad-hoc Network. How is that even possible?

Comment: If any Wi-Fi AP could perform a man-in-the-middle attack and break the encryption on all your HTTPS traffic, HTTPS would be trash. That's why you have to do client-side setup: to get your device to trust an impostor (your snooping proxy) that it shouldn't usually trust.

Comment: The article you linked to is mistaken. Those are the instructions for making a Mac act as a full AP, not just an ad hoc (IBSS) peer. Either way you still have to tell your client device to join the network it creates. These steps do not allow you to decrypt HTTPS (TLS). You would need to install a trusted root CA cert on the client for that. You might also need to configure the client to use your web proxy.